# Can I use a form for a single property of my object to be updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new in Rails (Rails 3). I have a '`color`' property in `MyObject` model, and this '`color`' property needs to be shown in a drop-down menu style. So I use Rails Helper  to implement this:

`select("myobject", COLORS, { :include_blank => false })`,

But, MyObject instance from DB is show in a table row, not a form. Only '`color`' property needs to use form  helper. My point is, I would like my '`color`' property to be shown in a drop-down menu, if I decide to use Rails form helper, can I use a Rails form helper for a single property('color') of a object and when the form is submitted, the whole object(in a table row) passed to controller will be updated? If so, how to implement the view, if not, what's the correct way to implement?

in side my controller, update method:

```
class MyobjectsController < ApplicationController
...
def update

     @myobject = myobject.find(params[:id])

     if @myobject.update_attributes(params[:myobject])
      puts @myobject.color #always get default value
      redirect_to myobject_path
    else
      redirect_to myobject_path
    end
  end
...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update individual attributes.  You're probably looking for a form like this:

```
form_for @myobject do |f|
  f.select :color, COLORS
end
```

You can also simplify your controller code:

```
def update
  @myobject = myobject.find(params[:id])

  if @myobject.update_attributes(params[:myobject])
    puts @myobject.color #always get default value
  end
  redirect_to myobject_path
end
```